# Mean coordinates of polygon in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-10

I need a way to get the mean (or median) coordinate of a polygon. With QGIS this is quite simple. But I need to do it with PostgreSQL.

There is the expression "st_GeometricMedian". But this only works with Points.

I thought that I am going to transform the polygon into the points with and get the median:

```
select
sourceeid,
ST_GeometricMedian((st_dumppoints(the_geom)).geom)
from 
polygons_view 
where 
sourceid=67475
```

But the result is that I get a line for every Point and then also a median for each line. But I need for one polygon one line.

How can I do this?

Comment: Oh I have forgotten that ST_Centroid isn't working because with some Polygons the Point is outside the polygon. And I always Need it inside

Comment: Since you are willing to ditch the mathematical definition of a center of mass, you could give a try to [`st_pointOnSurface`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointOnSurface.html)

Comment: Hi Thank you. This is also working. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming your polygon to points with `ST_Points` might help you with `st_GeometricMedian` works with points.

Comment: Thank you this works. I was thinking to complicated... :D